# How to compile a test snippet nicely with gnu make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I don't have a configure stage in my baseline (for various reasons), but I need to check whether my C compiler can support the -mavx2 flag or not.

If I have an empty file, call it `test.cc` then I can do something like:

```
$(CC) -mavx2 -c test.cc -o test.o
```

And check the return status code.  Obviously I don't want to leave those test.* files lying around though, but can't think of a good way to generate/test/delete them outside of a recipe.  Does anyone know of a good pattern to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Or, you could just take input from `stdin`, and output to `/dev/null`:

```
SUPPORTS_MAVX2:=$(shell echo 'void main(){}' | \
                gcc -x c -maxv3 -o /dev/null - 2>/dev/null; \
                echo $$?)
```

Then there are no artifact files to be deleted.   The `-x c` is necessary to tell gcc what language it is (as it can't determine that from the filename in this case), and you need the trailing `-` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can use "eval" to remove the temporary file and return the status code, so this works:

```
AVX2 = $(shell touch test.cc; $(CC) -mavx2 -c test.cc -o /dev/null >& /dev/null; eval "rm -f test.cc; echo $$?")
```

Edit and without the temporary file (assuming a sane system):

```
AVX2 = $(shell $(CC) -mavx2 -c /usr/include/stdlib.h -o /dev/null >& /dev/null; echo $?)
```

Comment: Why do you need to use eval?  You can just save the result in a variable.  Note, `>&` is not portable so you shouldn't use it.  You can use `$(shell ...$(CC) ... >/dev/null 2>&1; r=$$?; rm -f ...; exit $$r)`